# CString ReleaseBuffer() and terminating null character - C++

Tags: c++, memory, c-strings

```
#define LEN_CHART_NAME 25

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

char info1[125] ="000MyChartName2345678901234567890";
CStringA    name;
char*   str = NULL;
char    name_array[LEN_CHART_NAME];
memset(name_array,  0, LEN_CHART_NAME);     
str = name.GetBuffer(LEN_CHART_NAME + 1);
strncpy(str, &(chart_info1[3]), LEN_CHART_NAME);
//  str[LEN_CHART_NAME] = '\0';
name.ReleaseBuffer();
name.TrimRight();
strncpy(name_array, name, name.GetLength());
}
```

Question 1 - Is the line  //    str[LEN_CHART_NAME] = '\0'; necessary if I only use the name_array to package to a longer string later?

Question 2 - Do I need to name.ReleaseBuffer()?  I thought name memory will be released when it goes out of scope.

Question 3 - If I include the line str[LEN_CHART_NAME] = '\0';, Do I need to change     name.ReleaseBuffer();  to     name.ReleaseBuffer(-1);?